# Trying to get property 'name' of non-object - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to implement a search option  for some data in my Laravel app, but I have some problems with this:

```
public function index()
{

     $students= Student::all(); // When I use this form it appear all of Students even I put a name in Search option
     $students= new Student;//When I use this form I have this error: Trying to get property 'name' of non-object ...

    if (request()->filled('name')) {

       $students->where('name', '=', request()->input('name'));         
   }
    else{
           $students=Student::all();
    }
    return view('students.index',['students'=>$students]);
}
```

And my view is:

```
 <form action="{{action('StudentController@index')}}" class="d-flex w-100">
                <div class="col-4 p-0">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name">
                </div>
 </form>
```

When I try to display students' names, I get the error "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object"

Comment: What do you mean with search option...  Dropdown or autocomplete?

Comment: If its autocomplete, you can use this link: https://w3path.com/laravel-6-autocomplete-search-using-typeahead-js-example/

Comment: I updated my question, I added an image so it is clear now I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Students::all()` will return a collection of all students, `new Student` will return an empty model. Neither of these are what you want. Try this instead:

```
public function index()
{
    $request = request();
    if ($request->filled('name')) {
       // return a collection of students filtered by name
       $students = Student::where('name', $request->name)->get();         
    } else {
       // return a collection of all students
       $students = Student::all();
    }
    return view('students.index', compact('students'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code below:

```php
$students->where('name', '=', request()->input('name'));
```

You're not actually assigning the result of this query to anything. You can do it this way:

```
return App\Student::where('name', request()->input('name'))->get();
```

Or

```
$students = App\Student::where('name', '=', request()->input('name'))->get()
```

and then later return `students` in your function (if you do it the 2nd way)

The answer is that the result of your matching query isn't being assigned to the value you think you're returning.

Also, I don't know if there's a reason behind it but you don't need to store all the students in a variable and then query it. You can query the model directly by using it as seen in my examples above.